# Is there a difference between passing a function to a delegate by ref?

Tags: c#, reference, delegates, ref

I came upon this piece of C# code that uses delegates and passes the function to the delegate by reference...

```
        delegate bool MyDel(int x);
        static bool fun(int x) {
            return x < 0;
        }
        public static void Main() {
            var d1 = new MyDel(fun);       // what I usually write
            var d2 = new MyDel(ref fun);   
        }
```

The compiler didn't complain and built the project fine. I didn't find any difference while running some test cases, does this syntax make any difference than the usual syntax?

### Update

As **InBetween**  mentioned, it seems that this syntax is also valid (and it makes even less sense)

```
var d3 = new MyDel(out fun);
```

Comment: I've inspected the generated IL and can't find any difference. Normally passing a reference, would pass a the reference itself instead of a copy of the pointer to the reference.

Comment: @yanyankelevich - reference types and by ref are two separate concepts

Comment: ReSharper complains though: Cannot assign to 'fun' because it is a 'method group'

Comment: This seems like a language quirk (bug) more than anything else. `var d2 = new MyDel(ref fun);` doesn't make much sense, but `var d2 = new MyDel(out fun);` makes even less, and its also allowed.

Comment: The C# compiler is a bit too permissive here.  It otherwise matches behavior in the C and C++ languages, taking a reference of a function is a no-op in those languages as well.  You could file a bug with the Roslyn project, but this quirk has been around too long and is too innocent to generate much inspiration to fix it.  Click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues) if you want to tell them about it anyway.

Comment: My personal guess is that this is allowed because a delegate instance is just a wrapper of a compiler-written class i.e. a reference type; hence it's fine to pass this wrapper around with `ref` and `out` though most of times doing so doesn't really provide any benefit.

Answer (score 1):

it seems, in this case, there is no difference passing by ref / out / normal-way, 
I tried to see if any difference in ILDASM but no difference...

```
 delegate void MyDel();
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyDel myDel = new MyDel(Mtd1);
        MyDel d3 = new MyDel(ref Mtd1);
        MyDel d1 = new MyDel(ref Mtd2);
        MyDel d2 = new MyDel(out Mtd3);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I guess that's true and as Hans Passant has mentioned, the compiler seems to be too permissive here